# i can't connect redux with react-native app

Tags: react-native, authentication, redux, store

I have a problem with redux and react-native because I can't connect the state of the "login" view.
I would like to upload the user data and the token in the store.

In "AppState" View, I manage the actions :

```
import * as type from "../redux/actionTypes";
import {initialState} from "../redux/initialState";

export default function LoginStateReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch( action.type ) {
    case type.SET_LOGIN_STATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.user,
        token: action.token,
        isLoading: false,
        isLoggedIn: true,
      };
    case type.SET_LOGOUT_STATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null,
        token: null,
        isLoading: false,
        isLoggedIn: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

In "AppView", I manage the state :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer, useMemo } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import Login from './login/LoginViewContainer';

import { AuthContext } from './config/Context';
import * as type from '../redux/actionTypes'
import { initialState } from '../redux/initialState';
import LoginStateReducer from './AppState';

import Navigator from './navigation/Navigator';


const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

const [loginState, dispatch] = useReducer(LoginStateReducer, initialState);
  
  const authContext = useMemo(() => ({
    signIn: async(data) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      const token = String(data.token);
      const user= data.user;
      try {
        await AsyncStorage .setItem('token', token);
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      dispatch({ type: type.SET_LOGIN_STATE, user: user, token: token });
    },
    signOut: async() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      try {
        await AsyncStorage .removeItem('token');
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      dispatch({ type: type.SET_LOGOUT_STATE });
    },
  }), []);


  if( loginState.isLoading ) {
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      { loginState.token !== null ? (
        <Navigator onNavigationStateChange={() => {}} uriPrefix="/app" />
      )
    :
        <Login />
    }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In "AppViewContainer", I connect the reducer with the state :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose, lifecycle } from 'recompose';
import { Platform, UIManager } from 'react-native';

import AppView from './AppView';
import LoginStateReducer from './AppState';

export default compose(
  connect(
    state => ({
      user: state.user,
      token: state.token,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      LoginStateReducer: () => dispatch(LoginStateReducer()),
    })
  ),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
        UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
      }
      this.props.LoginStateReducer();
    },
  }),
)(AppView);
```

In the "reducer", I have :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

// ## Generator Reducer Imports
import LoginStateReducer from '../modules/AppState';

export default combineReducers({
  login: LoginStateReducer,
});
```

When I call the store once connected, it has not changed and I don't understand why :

```
"login": {"isLoading": true, "isLoggedIn": false, "token": "", "user": ""}
```

Can you tell me if i am missing something?

Thank you in advance for your feedback

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If you are using Redux, why are you using context here?
Also, generally you are writing a very outdated style of Redux here - modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers or `connect`. You might be following very outdated tutorials. Please read the official one: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: thanks for your feedback @phry but even though it's an old style of redux it should still work

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to make you aware of that. This would be a lot less code in modern Redux. My question about what you are doing here with Context and `useReducer` still stands. That does not communicate in any way with your Redux store.

Comment: thank you @phry. What is missing for that communicates? However, I do a "compose" and a "connect" in "AppViewContainer"

Comment: maybe I should manage the reducer in "LoginView" and not in "AppView"?

Comment: Redux manages your reducer. If you use `useReducer`, which is a React hook, not a Redux one, it will be local component state that never touches Redux.  You are mixing up a lot of stuff here.
Please read into this again, and do yourself a favor and follow the official resources.